# DynamoDB Java SDK JSON -> Item / top level Map<String, AttributeValue>

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

It appears to be easy to convert an `Item` to JSON via the `Item().toJSON()` method call using the Document API. However, how does one go the other way around?

Furthermore, how does one convert a JSON (or POJO for that matter) to `Map<String, AttributeValue>` which is effectively an `Item` in the original `AmazonDynamoDBClient` API

> Note I cannot use DynamoDB ORM i.e. DynamoMapper etc, since the underlying workload is both transactional and a bit more complex and would not allow annotations

I would've imagined the `Item` abstract to provide a method like: `Item.fromJSON(String json)` as a counterpart for `Item.toJSON()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer is the static method on `Item`, `Item.fromJSON()` i.e. a factory pattern

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.ItemUtils

val item = Item.fromJSON("""
    {
      "name": "Erfang"
    }
""".trimIndent())

ItemUtils.toAttributeValues(item)
```